# How do I replace static text with dynamic variable in Mandrill script

Tags: php, mandrill

I want to send emails to users once they fill and submit a form, I used POST method to capture the data, now I would like to replace static text with captured variables from the form. I have provide some variable samples of data from the form.

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];


$uri = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json';

$postString = '{
"key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"message": {
    "html": "this is the emails html content",
    "text": "this is the emails text content",
    "subject": "this is the subject",
    "from_email": "me@gmail.com",
    "from_name": "John",
    "to": [
        {
            "email": "me@yahoo.com",
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    ],
    "headers": {

    },
    "track_opens": true,
    "track_clicks": true,
    "auto_text": true,
    "url_strip_qs": true,
    "preserve_recipients": true,

    "merge": true,
    "global_merge_vars": [

    ],
    "merge_vars": [

    ],
    "tags": [

    ],
    "google_analytics_domains": [

    ],
    "google_analytics_campaign": "...",
    "metadata": [

    ],
    "recipient_metadata": [

    ],
    "attachments": [

    ]
},
"async": false
}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

```
$postString = '{
"key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"message": {
    "html": "'.$yourHTML.'",
    "text": "'.$yourTEXT.'",
    "subject": "this is the subject",
    "from_email": "me@gmail.com",
    "from_name": "John",
    "to": [
        {
            "email": "me@yahoo.com",
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    ],
    ...
```

But you don't specify where you want to put the dynamic datas.

But for your case it would be better to create a `PHP` array and then transform it using `json_encode`.

Comment: thanks Raphael you were very helpful, it worked just the way i wanted it

Comment: You're welcome! Don t forget to mark the question as solved!

Answer (score 1):

Just simply replace the static data with variables:

```
$postString = '{
"key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"message": {
"html": "",
"text": "$message",
"subject": "this is the subject",
"from_email": "me@gmail.com",
"from_name": "John",
"to": [
    {
        "email": "$email",
        "name": "$name"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

**Provide Merge Data through the API**

```
...
    "message": {
            "global_merge_vars": [
                {
                    "name": "var1",
                    "content": "Global Value 1"
                }
            ],
            "merge_vars": [
                {
                    "rcpt": "emailadress@domain.com",
                    "vars": [
                        {
                            "name": "fname",
                            "content": "John"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "lname",
                            "content": "Smith"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
    ...
```

**Format**

Merge tags use the following format, with a pipe (|) and asterisk (*) on each side of the merge tag name:

*|MERGETAG|*

In your template or content, merge tags might look like this:

```
Dear *|FNAME|*,

Thanks for your purchase on *|ORDERDATE|* from ABC Widget Company. We appreciate your business and have included a copy of your invoice below.

*|INVOICEDETAILS|*

-- ABC Widget Co.
```

There are three merge tags included in the previous examples. At the time of sending, provide global values and/or recipient-specific data for each merge tag.

**With Reference To:**

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582487-How-to-Use-Merge-Tags-to-Add-Dynamic-Content